# Debian find when packages in repository were last updated

Tags: debian, apt, repository

For instance:

```
sudo apt install qupzilla
```

works perfectly well.

Run Qupzilla, go to Help > About and you'll find the build date was in 2014.

How do I find that info from the command line *before* installing?

Edit

> Application version 1.6.6
> WebKit version 537.21
> © 2010-2014 David Rosca
> Build time: Sep 11 2014 17:14:39

Had I known this app was six years old I wouldn't have bothered.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the package changelog with:

```
apt-get changelog qupzilla
```

Comment: Good to know and more info than i had but no cigar. That documents changes to the package but does not speak to changes in the code.

Comment: The changelog entry will normally include "New upstream release", if package was rebuild based on a new version. That does not tell you exactly a version of the original code, but AFAIK is the best you can get, without downloading source package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-cache policy <packet_name>` to find the version currently in repo (the `Candidate` version in output)

Comment: Also good. Provides version but no build date.